# Why is Bind not seemingly not reloading my ACL's on service reload?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I have a two views setup on my ubuntu server:

```
acl members-nl {
    1.2.3.4;
};

acl members-eu {
};
```

I had the IP 1.2.3.4 inside members-eu and did *service bind9 reload* - its not taking affect. I can still see requests in my log using members-nl for the exact ip I am using.

How come reload doesn't work? When I do *service bind9 restart* it all seems to work fine.

I'd prefer it not to have to restart the entire service

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu's scripts but a 'reload' is typically telling BIND to recheck the zone files for updates, not its' entire configuration.  You should become familiar with the `rndc` command.  Besides reload, it also has a `reconfig` directive that tells BIND to reread it's config file.

Comment: What do your views look like? Have you set up them to use the ACL entries? Full configuration would help here.

Comment: Looking into the rndc commands now, seems like its the way to go.